# Django request.session is not passed to the next view

Tags: django, session, request, django-views

I am working with Django and I need to send data through `request.session`.
I have two simple views :

1. One that computes and displays the results to the user
2. One that saves the informations once the user has hit the "Validate" button

Here they are :

```
def import_trunk_con(request) :
    request.session.flush()

    trunks = []
    connections =[]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExcelFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)

        if form.is_valid():
            [trunks, connections] = handle_trunk_file(request.FILES['excel_import_file'])
    else:
        form = ExcelFileForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'trunk_list' : trunks,
        'connection_list' : connections
    }
    request.session['import_trunks'] = trunks
    request.session['import_connections'] = connections

    print(request.session['import_trunks']) #Prints the right result
    print(request.session['import_connections']) #Prints the right result
    template = loader.get_template('confWeb/import/import_trunk_con.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And

```
def import_recap_trunks(request):

    print('import_trunks' in request.session) #Result is False
    print('import_connections' in request.session) #Result is False
    if 'import_trunks' in request.session and 'import_connections' in request.session :
        print(request.session['import_trunks'])
        #Do some stuff with what's inside the session

        del request.session['import_trunks']
        del request.session['import_connections']
```

And here are my settings :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'confWeb.apps.ConfwebConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
```

The problem is that it is correctly stored in the session before trying to access the second view, but when we enter the second view, it's as if the session has been flushed.

I also realize that maybe I shouldn't use `request.session` for doing this, as I pass pretty big JSON objects. Maybe it's the problem ? The session cannot be this big ? 
If it's best to use something else, can you advise me ?

Comment: What is your `SESSION_ENGINE` setting? Do you have `django.contrib.sessions` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: I edited the question with the parameters you were asking for.

Comment: Big JSON objects could be the problem if you are storing sessions in cookies. I think the cookies can only be up to about 4 KB long.

Comment: Yeah then that's definitely the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use the `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db` backend:

```
# settings.py
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.db"
```

This will store all of the session data in the database on your server, while only sending a small ID to the client so that they don’t have all of the data.

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem because I indeed realized the JSON Objects I wanted to send were too big. I thought of using the database but didn't think of it this way. Thanks.